# android - TabLayout changing to fully black

Tags: android

I have created Tabs using TabLayout. When I am changing tabs front and back, sometimes in middle tab, whole tab layout becomes black. Everything else is working fine when I am back to first or last tab, again it shows everything perfectly. Only in middle tab it is creating problem.

Same code with 2 tabs is working perfectly.

Only with 3 Tab and in the centre of these 3 tabs it creates problem.

**When I am in first tab**

[image: When I am in first tab]

**When I am in second (middle) tab**

[image: When I am in second (middle) tab]

**Android Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**PageAdapter**

```
public class AboutPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"PhaseShift", "Core Committee", "Team"};
    private Context context;

    public AboutPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new AboutPhaseShiftFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new AboutCoreCommitteeFragment();
        } else {
            return new AboutAppWebTeamFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

**AboutCoreCommitteeFragment**

```
public class AboutCoreCommitteeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public AboutCoreCommitteeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment AboutCoreCommitteeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AboutCoreCommitteeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AboutCoreCommitteeFragment fragment = new AboutCoreCommitteeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_core_committee, container, false);

        ArrayList<Person> coreList = new ArrayList<>();

//        CODE HIDDEN

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.coreCommitteeList);
        PersonAdapter contactCoreAdapter = new PersonAdapter(getContext(), coreList);
        listView.setAdapter(contactCoreAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your middle fragment and adapter code.

Comment: Added PagerAdapter

Comment: AboutCoreCommitteeFragment() code..??

Comment: added AboutCoreCommitteeFragment()

Answer (score 0):

use background tag in your tablayout in XML

```
android:background="@color/white"
```